# Error when trying to RSA-decrypt a parameter string with libcrypto

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, pem, libcrypto

I am a beginner with the libcrypto library. I am trying to give an encrypted string to a function, decrypt it and return it decrypted. The string is encoded with my public key which which is 4096-bit sized.

```
char* decodeStr(const char* str, const size_t sizeStr)
{
    puts("Starting");
    FILE* file = fopen(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while trying to access to Presto's private key.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    RSA *privateKey = RSA_new();
    privateKey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(file, &privateKey, NULL, NULL);
    if (privateKey == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA private key.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return NULL;
    } 
    char* res = malloc(sizeStr);
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        perror("Memory allocating error ");
        return NULL;
    }
    const int sizeDecoded = RSA_private_decrypt(sizeStr, str, res, privateKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    if (sizeDecoded == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while decoding RSA-encoded wrapping key.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((res = realloc(res, (size_t)sizeDecoded)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Memory allocating error ");
        return NULL;
    }
    return res;

}
```

The following code outputs :

```
Starting
Error while decoding RSA-encoded wrapping key.
6928:error;04069506C:lib<4>:func<101>:reason<108>:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:518:
```

Since the error is unknown and I haven't been able to find any information about it on the net, and moreover I am a beginner with libcrypto, does `str`need to be in a certain format ?

Obivously it is this which breaks the program but I can't be sure of it, neither do I know how to fix this.

```
const int sizeDecoded = RSA_private_decrypt(sizeStr, str, res, privateKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

**EDIT :** I have been working with a client  which provides me those encoded dat for me to decrypt them. I don't know how they are processed exactly. Unfortunately, the encoded strings are even more *sensitive* than the private key itself, so I can't share it. It looks like `0c79cc00deb89a614db6ebe42be748219089fb5356` but with *1024* characters.

Comment: Can you share your ciphertext? And the code/command you used to encode the plaintext too.

Comment: I have been working with a client  which provides me those encoded data for me to decrypt them. I don't know how they processed it exactly. Unfortunately, the encoded strings are even more sensitive than the private key itself. It looks like `0c79cc00deb89a614db6ebe42be784821908e9fb5356` but with thousands of characters.

Comment: I'm not asking for the private key, just the ciphertext (the encrypted message)

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista I edited my question

Comment: You can download openssl source code and look at line 518 of rsa_eay.c, it will give you better idea of error

Comment: Be more specific than "thousands"

Comment: Related, you should probably avoid `RSA_public_encrypt` and `RSA_private_decrypt`. You should certainly avoid `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`. Instead of `RSA_*_{en|de}crypt`, use [EVP Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Asymmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption_of_an_Envelope). And use OAEP padding instead of PKCS padding. Also see Dr. Green's [A bad couple of years for the cryptographic token industry](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/21/bad-couple-of-years-for-cryptographic/).

Comment: Now open on the OpenSSL issue tracker: [Issue 3616, Missing error string for 4069506C:lib(64):func(1685):reason(108)](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3616).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

Your encoded strings

*0c79cc00deb89a614db6ebe42be748219089fb5356 but with thousands of characters.*

look like hexadecimal representation of the encoded message. I think you really need to convert the message to a *raw data*, converting hex to bytes.

Your strings are composed by `1024 (hex) chars` => `512 bytes` (you need two hex digits to represent one byte) => `4096 bits`, which is equal to the key length.

Try this simple function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void hex_2_bytes(uint8_t *des, char *source, size_t size);

int main()
{
                char *str = "0c79cc00deb89a614db6ebe42be748219089fb5356";
                uint8_t *dest = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * strlen(str) / 2);
                hex_2_bytes(dest, str, strlen(str));
                for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str) / 2; i++) {
                                printf(" %02X ", dest[i]);
                }
                return 0;
}

void hex_2_bytes(uint8_t *des, char *source, size_t size) {
                for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i+=2) {
                                sscanf(source+i, "%02x", des + (i/2));
                }
}
```

What is *raw data*? Your encrypted message is a string, which is an array of characters. I see only digits (from `0` to `9`) and the letters from `a` to `f`, which make me guess that your original message (which is, originally a binary string, *raw data*) has been represented as a very long number using hexadecimal digits. You need to convert it back.

If you have a message composed by *n* bytes, stored as a binary string (*raw data*), you will have an hexadecimal representation, stored as a text, which is *2*n* bytes long.

Example:

```
uint8_t raw_data_message[] = {0x3c, 0x2f};  // 2 bytes
char hex_representation_as_string_message[] = {'3', 'c', '2', 'f'}; // 4 bytes
```

Your messages a like `hex_representation_as_string_message`, but you need them as `raw_data_message`.

#### The solution

Here's a fully working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define PRIVATE_KEY_PATH ".ssh/id_rsa"

/*
 * Generation of the encrypted message:
 * echo "Hello, this is a super secret message" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pem >message.encrypted
 *
 * Resulting encrypted message in hex representation:
 * 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
 * (converted with: hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' message.encrypted)
 */

void hex_2_bytes (uint8_t *des, char *source, size_t size);

int decode (uint8_t *dest, const uint8_t *src, const size_t size);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    // Reading the encrypted message in hex representation
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error while trying to access to the encrypted message"
                       ".\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *hex_repr = malloc(fsize);
    fread(hex_repr, fsize, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    printf("Hexadecimal representation of the encrypted message\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < fsize; ++i) {
        printf("%c", hex_repr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSize: %d\n", fsize);

    // Converting to raw data
    size_t raw_data_size = fsize / 2;
    uint8_t *raw_data = (uint8_t *) malloc(
            raw_data_size * sizeof(uint8_t));
    hex_2_bytes(raw_data, hex_repr, (size_t) fsize);
    printf("Raw encrypted message\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < raw_data_size; ++i) {
        printf("%02X", raw_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSize: %d\n", raw_data_size);

    // Decryption
    char *res = malloc(raw_data_size * sizeof(char));
    if (res == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocating error ");
        return -1;
    }
    int msg_size = decode(res, raw_data, raw_data_size);
    printf("Decrypted message:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < msg_size; ++j) {
        printf("%c", res[j]);
    }
    printf("\nSize: %d\n", msg_size);

    return 0;
}

void hex_2_bytes (uint8_t *des, char *source, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 2) {
        sscanf(source + i, "%02x", des + (i / 2));
    }
}

int decode (uint8_t *res, const uint8_t *src, const size_t size) {
    puts("Starting");
    FILE *file = fopen(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error while trying to access to Presto's private key.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    RSA *privateKey = RSA_new();
    privateKey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(file, &privateKey, NULL, NULL);
    if (privateKey == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA private key.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    const int sizeDecoded = RSA_private_decrypt(size, src, res,
                                                privateKey,
                                                RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    if (sizeDecoded == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Error while decoding RSA-encoded wrapping key.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    return sizeDecoded;
}
```

And the results (as a proof of work):

[image: Proof of work]

Note that I'm using 2048 bit rsa keys.

Comment: I agree, it will halve the length of your data and probably solve the problem of the key length.

Comment: So decoding hex data is *not possible* with libcrypto ? I have found out the **EVP Tools*, can't it  decrypt hex data too ?

Comment: You need just to convert your data from hex presentation to binary representation. The function *hex_2_bytes* in my answer should to the work, so please, give it a try.
By the way, I didn't know *EVP Tools*, let me see if it could be helpfu

Comment: Ps: when I say binary representation, I actually mean *raw data*

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista I haven't been able to make it work. I might use your function for the same purpose but with the *EVP tools*.

Comment: Also, I am not sure to understand the difference between *binary representation* and *raw data*. Could you explain the difference, may be by editing your answer ?

Comment: Updated. I hope that it's more clear now. I will provide you a sample code to solve your problem.

Comment: You meant `0x3c` or `{ '3', 'f', '2', 'f'}` no ? It is more clear indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, sorry, it's a typo

Comment: @Badda check out the last update to the answer. I've added a fully working example.

Answer (score 1):

I solved part of the issue. I added :

```
/* Load the human readable error strings for libcrypto */
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
```

At the beginning of the function. The output turned into :

```
Starting
Error while decoding RSA-encoded wrapping key.  
1124:errir:0406506C:rsa routines: RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:518:
```

Which I guess means that the length of the key is too small for the provided data. Still left to know if the data is wrong, the key is wrong and how to fix it.

Also, to avoid making such mistakes later, I added :

```
const size_t sizeRSA = RSA_size(prestoPrivateKey);
if (sizeRSA < sizeWrappingKey)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Size of key : %d\n Size of data : %d\n The size of the key should higher than data length.\n", sizeRSA, sizeWrappingKey);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Output the length of key and length of data ... see if one of them is not as you expected

Comment: In case you're unaware, the message to decode must be shorter than the key length. Normal process for RSA encryption of data is that the data is packed into key-length-sized blocks using a PKCS#1 algorithm, so if by "thousands" you mean "more than 1 block" then perhaps you should decrypt a block at a time and see what comes out

Comment: Your messages is an hex string, which means that is double the size it should be.